# How to set the word wrap property to particular column using PhpExcel in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I want to set the wordwrap property to a particular column. I have set the fixed width for that column. But when text is large it goes into the next cell. I want to wrap that text in same column.

I am using the phpExcel extension to export the data.

Here is the code.

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, "Sr No");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, "Query");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $row, "Additional Detail.");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(60);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(60);
```

Want to set wordwrap property to column B in my above code.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wordwrap is set for individual cells, or for a range of cells, not for a specific column

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B1:B100')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```

You may also want to set vertical alignment for those cells as well

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B1:B100')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
```

Comment: I think we can set the Wordwrap to individual column. I did this way     `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);` But when I set this it's style gets removed.

Comment: @Nitin - you can try doing that, but it won't work, PHPExcel does not support row or column styles

Comment: I already set the style for whole sheet. But when I set wordwrap property to column as above it doesn't display the style for that column. Do you have any idea?